# Why OpportunityShare object and UserRecordAccess objects giving different access level

Tags: opportunity, sharing, standard-objects, apex-managed-sharing

I am not sure why `OpportunityShare` object and `UserRecordAccess` objects are giving different access level for a particular record and user combination.

If i run following query on UserRecordAccess object and try to extract HasEditAccess field it return FALSE.

> SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId
>   ='00570000001pGWABA2' AND RecordId ='006Q000000Bt1eMIBR'  // Returns false

but

If i run follwoing query on OpportunityShare object it returns Edit access.

> select OpportunityAccessLevel from OpportunityShare WHERE
>   UserOrGroupId ='00570000001pGWABA2' AND OpportunityId
>   ='006Q000000Bt1eMIBR' // Edit

I am not sure why both queries returning different results?

If i have shared an opportunity with some other user using Apex and grant him `Edit` right then `UserRecordAccess` object must return True for that particular user and opportunity combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing object-level and record-level permissions. Profiles and permission sets determine how a user can interact with an object, such as Leads, Accounts, and Opportunities. Unless you set View All/Modify All for an object that user may or may not have access to individual records.

Sharing rules modify which records a user can see and edit, providing the user's profile allows for such actions. I can share Opportunities with a user, but if that user's profile does not provide at least Read access to Opportunities that user will never see those records.

**Update**

UserRecordAccess tells you what access the user has to a particular record; this is the culmination of all of the security settings, starting with the user's profile and assigned permission sets and then applying your global security settings and sharing rules.

If a user is not assigned a profile or permission set granting Edit to the object then UserRecordAccess will always be false since the user does not have access to edit that object.

Comment: you mean UserRecordAccess object shows record access permissions as per your profile permission on that object?

Comment: Please see my update for an explanation.

Comment: Very nice. Now every thing is clear to me. Thanks a lot @Mike

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that the profile restricts edit on Opportunities ? I don't know how Apex manual sharing handles this...